# Redirect audio stream delivered by TTS to a virtual sound card

Tags: c#, speech, text-to-speech

I developed a program that translates speech from one language to another (you talk in English, I hear it in French). I used for that TTS `Microsoft.Speech;`.

How can a redirect the audio stream delivered by TTS to use it as microphone for other VoIP applications like Skype for example?

I found many programs that can do so, but none of them as .NET solutions.

Do you have any idea how can I configure a virtual sound card with C#, C++ or even C?

Comment: Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: If you found solutions that work without .NET, you could implement a C++/CLI wrapper to call those programs.

Comment: Yeah i know but i'm stuck in here!! i can't find any good solution!!